# Eclipse WindowBuilder change font size in pallette

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I need to change the palette text size because it is too small for my eyes.

i tried to do it through the properties but it always goes back to the same size. i even change the whole font through colors and fonts in the preferences but same result.

Comment: What do you mean by _"through the properties"_? By what does it _"go back"_? By closing and reopening the WindowBuilder editor? What do you mean by _"the whole font"_? Please describe how to reproduce your issue, so accurately that one does not need to guess. And please also tell the version of the WindowBuilder you use. It might related to [this](https://github.com/eclipse-windowbuilder/windowbuilder/issues/486).

Comment: i go to the palette settings and change the font for example to Segeo UI 18 it immediately goes back to Segoe UI 9  after i click ok i am using version 4.29

Comment: There is no WindowBuilder 4.29. 4.29 is probably the version of the Eclipse platform you use. What you are saying sounds like a bug. So, if you can reproduce it in the current WindowBuilder version, make sure it has been reported to WindowBuilder project, best with a pull request that fixes the issue.